# Query with multiple conditions on one column in the database, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get users whose level is from one to another value. Well, i don't know, how to make a correct query. This is my bad try:

```
$thread = Threads::findOrFail($id);

$users= Users::where(
          ['rank', '>', $thread->rank_from], 
          ['rank', '<', $thread->rank_to]
          )->get();
```

My error is:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from accounts where (0 = rank and 1 = > and 2 = 21))

Thank you!

Comment: My error is: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `accounts` where (`0` = rank and `1` = > and `2` = 21))

Comment: What are `$user->level_from` and `$user->level_to`? Your query is `User::where()`, so why would it be querying `accounts`? We're missing some information here... Also, post all your information into the question, not the comments (I've done this for you, but it's up to you to edit your question in the future). ALSO, unrelated, but models in Laravel are singular by convention, `User`, not `Users`.

Comment: I need to get users who match the level of access to the topic from one value to another.
```
$users = Users::where(
          ['rank', '>', $thread->rank_from], 
          ['rank', '<', $thread->rank_to]
          )->get();
```

Comment: you are passing 2 parameters in `where`, when you want to put multiple where statements you need to pass an array as the first parameter which contains your sub arrays

Comment: ^ That's it; missed the parent array. `Users::where([['rank', '>', $thread->rank_from], ['rank', '<', $thread->rank_to]])->get()`

Comment: it's simpler (and readable) to just do two `where`s @TimLewis

Comment: @N69S 100% agree, but the array syntax is available, they're just using it incorrectly :) (Voted on your answer though; would have solved the issue from the get-go)

Comment: Yes, thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 5):

Change it to this format for parenthesis. But here since it's both an AND conditions, you dont really need the parenthesis, unless you're not showing us the whole request and you have some orWhere in it...

```
$users = Users::where(function ($query) use ($thread) {
             $query->where('level', '>', $thread->level_from)
                 ->where('level', '<', $thread->level_to);
          })->get();
```

Here it is in the documentation [Eloquent queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses)

If the query you posted is the whole query, just stack the `where`s

```
$users= Users::where('rank', '>', $thread->rank_from)
            ->where('rank', '<', $thread->rank_to)
            ->get();
```